# Asynchronous data reading from server using WinSock

Tags: c++, winapi, asynchronous, winsock, winsock2

I am using the WinSock API in C++ to connect and send data to a specific server (to increase readability, all the code is without error handling):

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define PORT 5051

WSADATA WsaData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WsaData);

SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
SOCKADDR_IN sin;

ZeroMemory(&sin, sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(PORT);
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("Some valid IP");

connect(s, (sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin));

string sdata_out = "Something like GET request\n";
send(s, sdata_out.c_str(), sdata_out.size(), 0);
```

The server will start to sending responses, separated by different periods of time. It will send responses without additional requests from me.

I need to read this data asynchronously (not cycle of `recv()` functions). 
I tried to use `WSAEventSelect()` to listen on the local socket, like this:

```
SOCKET sloc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
SOCKADDR_IN sinloc;

ZeroMemory(&sinloc, sizeof(sinloc));
sinloc.sin_family = AF_INET;
sinloc.sin_port = htons(PORT);
sinloc.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

WSAEventSelect(sloc, EventArray[EventTotal - 1], FD_ACCEPT | 
    FD_CLOSE | FD_READ | FD_CONNECT) == SOCKET_ERROR)

bind(sloc, (sockaddr *)&sinloc, sizeof(sinloc));

listen(sloc, 5));
```

I have no idea what to do further. I tried [following this example](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancediomethod5d.html), but my program got stuck at runtime on this code:

```
DWORD Event = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(EventTotal, EventArray, FALSE, WSA_INFINITE, FALSE)
```

What is the problem? How should my event handler function look? Or, am I am doing something fundamentally wrong? Is there a correct way to asynchronously read data from the server, if I don't know when the data comes?

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576.aspx) tells you what happens, when one of the requested network events happen. The events do not trigger an event handler, as you assume. Your problem is not, how an event handler should look like, but rather, how to wait for an event. Our problem is, that we don't know your code. The code you posted is both incomplete, as well as invalid. It will not compile.

Comment: what sense read data asynchronous and connect/send synchronous ? why you use `connect` and `send` instead single asynchronous call to `ConnectEx` ? why you use the worst way `WSAEventSelect` instead iocp ?

Comment: @IInspectable, it is incomplete due to highlight problem places. "How to wait for an event" piece i just copied from listed example. Approximately it looks like:
`while(1) {  Event = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(EventTotal, EventArray, 
                                    FALSE,WSA_INFINITE, FALSE);

WSAEnumNetworkEvents(SocketArray[Event - WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0]->Socket, EventArray[Event - WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0], &NetworkEvents);

    if (NetworkEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_ACCEPT) {"event handling code"}`

Comment: Nothing to do with highlighting. `WSAEventSelect(sloc, EventArray[EventTotal - 1], FD_ACCEPT | FD_CLOSE | FD_READ | FD_CONNECT) == SOCKET_ERROR)` simply will not compile.

Comment: @IInspectable, ofc sry there was error checking like `if (WSAEventSelect(..., ..., ...) == SOCKET_ERROR)`, i just forgot to delete ending part while posting